# How to parse a large dataset using python into a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, space, delimited

I have a large .dat file (3gigs) which contains values separated by space. Here's how the first first line looks like:

```
  S       201001        7            2                2                             30105                                            2  011    06   1  123                         3405   1   06  01           2    2                                      0321          1006  314           2000                                     2   222                   2 2               2     2  2          122222 11      3    094     1            M 04  200940   39072       3941    083                              22       2    2  2 2                                             110 110 00   0000000    00      000000000 000000  000      000000000000000000011                  101              1   111            1 0      1     1  1        111111                11       1    1  1 1
```

And I have a cheat sheet which mentions the column names and the position of values for them. For eg: Name 15-18, Age 55-56 etc.

So, I am new to python and my question is how can I parse this large dataset using python and save it into a CSV file with column names at the top and values under them.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is space-separated values and not fixed offsets? E.g., does "Name 15-18" mean "bytes 15-18 of each row is the Name"?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you against doing it in Python. I needed to perform similar operations for a migration and I eventually ran Sed from my Python scripts.
I can assure you that investing a little time learning how to use Sed will pay off. http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html
If you are on Unix it's probably already there, if you are on Windows, you can get Cygwin.